# A better formula to rank by best position from 3 test result?

Tags: excel, rank

Based on 3 control tests (test1, test2 and test3) I want to make a ranking of the best results by the users. I used rank () at each test (1,2,3) then summed up the result and used rank () and countif () again to make the final ranking. The problem is that the ranking is not accurate even if I use rank () or countif. For example in B.G. should have a better position in the final standings than A.C. because in test 2 and 3 it has better results than B.G., a higher number.

- Ranking test 1 `=COUNTIF(C$3:C$32,"<"&C3)+COUNTIF(C$3:C3,C3)`
- SUM `=SUM(G3:I3)`
- COUNTIF `=COUNTIF(K$3:K$32,"<"&$K3)+COUNTIF($K$3:$K3,$K3)`

Any better solution?

[image: Table attached]

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to add the three results and rank their total. However, in order to do so the individual test results must first be converted to a common denominator. The critical information for this purpose is the maximum achievable in each test.

Assuming that the maximum is 10 points in each test then the result of Test 1 can be converted simply by inverting the available result (10 - [result]). But if the maximum is different you might use a percentage. A candidate scoring 63%, 82% and 51% in the three tests could simply be given a total score of 196 (Sum) or 65.333 (Avg) and either number is suitable for ranking.

Comment: I am struggle to put your idea in a formula, should I use max() to find the highest number for test1 (or test2, test3) then convert the result to a percentage?
`1 L.N. 2.14 253 145 86.64% 100.00% 100.00% 95.55% 1` 
'=D6/max($D$6:$D$35)' - D6 - result from test 1
'95.55%' = average from 86.64%, 100% and 100%
'1" - result from rank()

Comment: You need a helper column for each ranking you want: Best in Test1, Best in Test2, Best in Test3 and Best overall = 4 columns. The 4th one would contain `= Avg(G3:i3)` where G3:I3 contain results from C3:E3 expressed as percentages. Use the RANK() function on each column individually, like `RANK(G3, $G$3:$G$100,0)` - 0 for ascending, 1 for descending, `RANK.EQ()` in 365. If you only need the overall result, concatenate the 3 formulas for the tests into a single result using +.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t14fllv4zndqno6/final.PNG?dl=0
I think you mean something like this? Used min() because lower value is better.

Comment: but there is still a lot of work to be done, some students are not positioned correctly in the final ranking..

Comment: All the calculations appear correct. You may want to sort the sheet on the AVG column so that the sequence changes to that indicated by the ranks. - Not really a "lot of work" :-)